# How to copy CellComments to new cell (when copying an entire sheet)

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I am trying to copy a CellComment to a new cell (using Apache POI).  I know I have to create  new comment (as opposed to just setting the old comment in to the new cell), but I can't seem to be able to find out how to duplicate the Anchor.

```
private void createComment(Cell aNewCell, Comment theOldComment) {
    CreationHelper createHelper = aNewCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
    ClientAnchor anchor = createHelper.createClientAnchor();
    // How to get the old CellComment anchor for x1, c2, y1, y2???
    Drawing drawing = aNewCell.getSheet().createDrawingPatriarch();
    Comment aNewComment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
    aNewComment.setString(theOldComment.getString());
    aNewCell.setCellComment(aNewComment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Patriarch instead of `CreationHelper`. Create Anchor from the `HSSFPatriarch`'s object and pass the values as parameters to the `createAnchor` function. Hope this helps.

```
 HSSFPatriarch drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
 ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(10, 20, 30, 40, (short)4, 2, (short)6, 5);
```

Hope this helps.

```
 private void createComment(HSSFCell aNewCell, Comment theOldComment) {
        HSSFPatriarch drawing = aNewCell.getSheet().getDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(drawing.getChildren().get(0).getAnchor().getDx1(),
                drawing.getChildren().get(0).getAnchor().getDx2(), drawing.getChildren().get(0).getAnchor().getDy1(),
                drawing.getChildren().get(0).getAnchor().getDy2(), (short)4, 2, (short)6, 5);
        Comment aNewComment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
        aNewComment.setString(theOldComment.getString());
        aNewCell.setCellComment(aNewComment);
    }
```